# After upgrading spring version getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, spring, pom.xml

I'm trying to upgrade spring from 2.1.1 to 2.2.0 in multiple projects that we have.
I already done it in a few projects and all went smooth.

In the current project, I did the same changes :

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    ...
    ...

</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        .....
        .....
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

Now when I try to start my app I'm getting the following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy
```

I checked and according to the doc this class should be available in my current spring-core version : 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/MergedAnnotations.SearchStrategy.html

stack trace :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.isComponent(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:279) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:128) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:691) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:392) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:197) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:70) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
```

maven dependencies tree, all spring occurrences :

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       |  \- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form-spring:jar:3.8.0:compile
```

Comment: When using Spring Cloud you cannot simply upgrade Spring Boot. You also have to upgrade Spring Cloud to a version that supports that Spring Boot version. The older Spring Cloud dependency pulls in old Spring dependencies hence your exception.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I tried to upgrade the spring-cloud to Hoxton  version, but it didnt help

Comment: You don't need the `spring-boot-dependencies` as is already implied by the parent you have added. If the upgrade of Spring Cloud doesn't work there must be another dependency pulling in the older version of Spring (or you did it yourself). Use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out what is leading to the old version of Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum in the dependency tree, I should search for old versions of spring.framework.core ? I added the dependency tree , but I didnt find any old version of spring framework.core

Comment: Chances are there is something wrong with your dependency tree... and your IDE may be compounding the problem. Fix the dependencies are stated in the comments, clear your IDE caches if any, quit your IDE, delete the "target" directories then start your IDE again and do a full compile.

Comment: based on the current dependency tree, does it look fine ?

Comment: I wonder why ever dependency is listed twice in the dependency tree output. I would assume that is a copy/paste error but... how would you manage that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference : [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions)

When artifacts that are part of the Spring IO Platform are declared without a version , a predefined version of the dependency will be used and for spring-core it is

> org.springframework spring-core 5.0.13.RELEASE

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.13.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/ is missing the MergedAnnotations class.

Declare the dependency with the version of your choice

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Update** (My earlier answer appears a bit misleading )

Explictly declaring the version is not required . [Dependency Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-dependency-management) section of the documentation mentions the following.

> Each release of Spring Boot provides a curated list of dependencies
>   that it supports. In practice, you do not need to provide a version
>   for any of these dependencies in your build configuration, as Spring
>   Boot manages that for you. When you upgrade Spring Boot itself, these
>   dependencies are upgraded as well in a consistent way.

Also , the upgrade modifications required when inherting the starter parent is explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-parent-pom)

Comment: Please check the jar added as part of Maven dependencies to verify the version

Comment: the jar that is added is from version 5.2.0

Comment: From https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud Release train Finchley is compatible with  Spring boot version 2.0.x . Try upgrading that to Hoxton to be compatible with Spring boot version 2.2.x